# My program does not work without printf

Tags: c, printf

I have an interesting problem that I can't figure out.
My program doesn't work without printf

```
printf("",L[i-1][j][k],L[i][j-1][k],L[i][j][k-1],L[i-1][j][k-1],L[i-1][j-1][k],L[i][j-1][k-1],L[i-1][j-1][k-1]);
```

I don't mean printf("%s",S); under main, I mean printf under getLCS function. With printf the output of this program is "fskxft" the proper answer. Without printf the output of the program is "(w"
How can it be possible?
Here is my code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>

    void findLCS(char*, char*, char*, int, int, int);
    int*** allocMem(int, int, int);
    void fillMatrix(char*, char*, char*, int***, int, int, int);
    char* getLCS(char*, int***, int, int, int);
    int findMax(int, int, int);
    void freeMem(char*, char*, char*, int***, char*, int, int);

    int main()
    {
        char* X = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
        char* Y = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
        char* Z = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
        X = "bccmzzzxxyizqnlovffmrudbcywrsqkjcxhexftf";
        Y = "kcftkzdlsyjkxkjxfcjhbfkkdwcrgnjdxtgkaxhm";
        Z = "vihfjvbvsklwyxyzobeztllmvfdgsvekcvtqugjw";

        int m = strlen(X);
        int n = strlen(Y);
        int o = strlen(Z);

        int*** L = allocMem(m,n,o);
        fillMatrix(X,Y,Z,L,m,n,o);
        char *S = getLCS(Z,L,m,n,o);
        printf("%s",S);
        freeMem(X,Y,Z,L,S,m,n);

      return 0;
    }

    int*** allocMem(int m, int n, int o)
    {
        int x = m+1, y = n+1, z = o+1;
        int i, j;

        //Allocating Memory
        int *entries = malloc(x * y * z * sizeof(entries));
        int ***L = malloc(x * sizeof(int **));
        for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            L[i] = malloc(y * sizeof(int *));
            for(j = 0; j < y; j++)
            {
                L[i][j] = entries + (i * y * z) + (j * z);
            }
        }
        return L;
    }
    void fillMatrix(char* X, char* Y, char* Z, int*** L, int m, int n, int o)
    {
        int i, j, k;
        //Filling the LCS matrix
        for (i=0; i<=m; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<=n; j++)
            {
                for(k=0; k<=o; k++)
                {
                    if (i == 0 || j == 0 || k == 0)
                    {
                        L[i][j][k] = 0;
                    }
                    else if ((X[i-1] == Y[j-1]) && (Y[j-1] == Z[k-1]))
                    {
                        L[i][j][k] = L[i-1][j-1][k-1] + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        L[i][j][k] = findMax(L[i-1][j][k], L[i][j-1][k], L[i][j][k-1]);        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    char* getLCS(char* Z, int*** L, int m, int n, int o)
    {
        int i, j, k;
        int l = L[m][n][o];
        char* S = malloc(l*sizeof(*S));
        int c= l-1;
        int jj, kk;
        for (i=m; i>0; i--)
        {
            for (j=n; j>0; j--)
            {
                if(j > jj)
                {
                    j = jj;
                }
                for(k=o; k>0; k--)
                {
                    if(k > kk)
                    {
                        k = kk;
                    }
                    printf("",L[i-1][j][k],L[i][j-1][k],L[i][j][k-1],L[i-1][j][k-1],L[i-1][j-1][k],L[i][j-1][k-1],L[i-1][j-1][k-1]);
                    if(L[i-1][j][k] == c && L[i][j-1][k] == c && L[i][j][k-1] == c && L[i-1][j][k-1] == c && L[i-1][j-1][k] == c && L[i][j-1][k-1] == c && L[i-1][j-1][k-1] == c && L[i][j][k] == c+1)
                    {
                        S[c]=Z[k-1];
                        c--;
                        i=i-1;
                        j=j-1;
                        k=k-1;
                        jj = j;
                        kk = k;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        S[l] = '\n';
        return S;
    }

    int findMax(int a, int b, int c)
            {
        int max = a;
        if(b>max)
        {
            max = b;
        }
        if(c>max)
        {
            max = c;
        }
        return max;
    }

    void freeMem(char* X, char* Y, char* Z, int*** L, char* S, int m, int n)
    {
        int i, j;
        int x = m+1, y = n+1;
        free(X);
        free(Y);
        free(Z);
        for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < y; j++)
            {
                free(L[i][j]);
            }
            free(L[i]);
        }
        free(L);
    }
```

Comment: probably a buffer overrun, but honestly I don't want to wade through that code.

Comment: This is almost exactly the same question as this deleted one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016099/my-program-does-not-work-without-printf

Comment: Debugging is an extremely useful skill. The OP of this answer suggested single-stepping. This was a fairly good direction to go in, but stepping isn't the only form of debugging, and it wouldn't quickly and clearly identify the issue. Perhaps a more suitable form of debugger in this scenario, would be a memory profiler such as valgrind which will bring to light all of the memory-related violations your program encounters during runtime.

Comment: You should try to provide a minimal (not-)working example. Nobody wants to go through all that code, it's a waste of our time.

Comment: @minitech I request that you review the decision to convert ashirk's answer to a comment. It is now more suitable as an answer to this question, according to the FAQ.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: If you could quote the particular section of the help centre that changes things, that would be helpful =) It doesn’t matter much, as this question is closed and not really likely to be helpful to anyone as-is, except for the general debugging advice (which can be found elsewhere).

Comment: @minitech I'm aware that comments are preferred for requesting clarification, but it is clear in this case that the asker hasn't tried using the appropriate debugger. I would argue that learning memory debugging skills is the right direction. [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) section "Answer the question" states that "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful".

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: Noted, but it’s my opinion that it’s not an answer. If you’d like to take that up with another moderator, flag, please.

Comment: @ashirk I initialized all variables, the problem has been solved thanks a lot

Comment: @minitech There are 72 votes on the community wiki answer for the meta question entitled ["What is an acceptable answer?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer) that disagree with you... Perhaps it might be a good idea to modify that. If you don't believe the answer was helpful, see the comment immediately above this one.

Answer (score 3):

For a start this code is incorrect

```
    char* X = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
    char* Y = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
    char* Z = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
    X = "bccmzzzxxyizqnlovffmrudbcywrsqkjcxhexftf";
    Y = "kcftkzdlsyjkxkjxfcjhbfkkdwcrgnjdxtgkaxhm";
    Z = "vihfjvbvsklwyxyzobeztllmvfdgsvekcvtqugjw";
```

As you have a memory leak as the strings are not stored in the allocated memory.

Use `strcpy` - Then using free will work as expected.

Comment: thnx this is very helpful